# Generating unique random value in Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I tried to generate large numbers of unique random values using np.random.randint but it returned few duplicates values.

I have following dataset

```
District    Prefix  Quota       
A           98426   783
A           98427   223
A           98446   127
A           98626   51
B           98049   167
B           98079   153
B           98140   120
B           98159   139
B           98169   182
B           98249   86
B           98426   588
B           98446   96
C           98049   104
C           98060   68
C           98149   65
C           98150   68
C           98159   86
C           98160   80
C           98169   113
```

Code to reproduce:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['A', 98426, 783],
    ['A', 98427, 223],
    ['A', 98446, 127],
    ['A', 98626, 51],
    ['B', 98049, 167],
    ['B', 98079, 153],
    ['B', 98140, 120],
    ['B', 98159, 139],
    ['B', 98169, 182],
    ['B', 98249, 86],
    ['B', 98426, 588],
    ['B', 98446, 96],
    ['C', 98049, 104],
    ['C', 98060, 68],
    ['C', 98149, 65],
    ['C', 98150, 68],
    ['C', 98159, 86],
    ['C', 98160, 80],
    ['C', 98169, 113]
], 
    columns=['District', 'Prefix', 'Quota'])
```

I had to create a unique random number and add it to the prefix. the number of random values is given in Quota

```
np.random.seed(1)  # for repeatability 
random=df.Prefix.repeat(df.Quota)*100000 + np.random.randint(0, 99999, df.Quota.sum())
```

I thought np.random.randint gave unique numbers but while generating around 18000 numbers, it gave around 200 duplicate number.
eventually I tried random.sample and problem was fixed. but I want to generate unique numbers using np.random.randit because I can change seed in np.random.seed(n) and can create another set of unique numbers different from first set by changing seed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able directly with `np.random.randint`, since it doesn't offer the possibility to randomly sample *without replacement*. But [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) does. And by specifying a random seed, you can reproduce the generated sequence, which will consist on a random, uniformly sampled distribution array within the range `range(99999)`:

```
np.random.seed(2)  
numbers = np.random.choice(range(99999), size=df.Quota.sum(), replace=False)
random = df.Prefix.repeat(df.Quota)*100000 + numbers
```

---

```
len(random)==random.nunique()
# True
```

Comment: thanks it worked but the values generated by np.random.seed(1) and np.random.seed(2) have duplicated values. np.random.seed(1) gives unique set and so does np.random.seed(2). but merging both values gives duplicate values

Comment: Yes, that is expectable though right @YubrajBhusal ? You're generating independent sequences, why should it guarantee that these *also* have no repeated samples? `np.random.choice` has no idea of the previously generated sequence, regardless of the random seed

Comment: how do you suggest I can create a sets of number which will be unique from previous set?

Comment: What you can do... is generate an even larger array, o size say `df.Quota.sum()*10`, and split that into 10 different arrays, which will be unique @YubrajBhusal

Comment: how can  can I group by "prefix" column and create random number among them, so that each prefix will have chance to get random number from 0 to 99999. the above code creates random number total of "Quota" column and add prefix to them. by doing that not all prefix gets chance to get random number from 0 to 99999. I want to put np.random.choice on prefix, so that every other prefix gets chance to get random number from 0 to 99999. thanks in advance